# JQGrid refreshIndex() method for local data not clearing previous index array

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have local data delete functionality:

```
$.each(rowids, function() {  // - delete selected rows
                $grid.delRowData(this);
            });
```

I noticed that after this call, doing retrieving the _index:

```
var xref = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', '_index');
```

the _index still contains the deleted row.

I looked into the JQGrid source, after the deletion of the local data, a call to refreshIndex() is made.  I noticed that the Index is not removed, but rather the existing array is overwritten:

```
for (i = 0; i < datalen; i++) {
            val = $.jgrid.getAccessor(ts.p.data[i], idname);
            if (val === undefined) { val = String(i + 1); }
            ts.p._index[val] = i;
        }
```

I added the following right before the loop above:

```
ts.p._index = [];
```

This appears to resolve my issue, will this cause problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are right. One could change [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L3169) of `delRowData` to

```js
delete $t.p._index[id];
```

and one should add the line

```js
ts.p._index = [];
```

before [the loop](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L1208) exactly like you suggested.

I think you should post the corresponding bug report to [trirand](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs).

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I will post a note when I get in to work Monday.